# Gererate SharePoint entity class from xsd/xml

Tags: sharepoint, xsd

I am creating one SharePoint project and want to use entity class like generated in http://sitecollecmgmt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets this projects ( Groups,Users and Roles helper class).Can anyone tell me how can I get SharePoint xsd/xml to generate this type helper classes from xsd tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the XSD files and then run `xsd /c schema1.xsd schema2.xsd ...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but my question is how/where can get these xsd files in sharepoint 2010